# Writing to android wear locally

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to write a continuous stream of data to android wear locally on the wear device. I've a class called DataSaver that works perfectly fine on the phone side, but the same code would not work on the wear device. I've android permission for write, and read on both wear and mobile.

In the constructor for DataSaver, I've the following:

```
if (!isExternalStorageWritable()) Log.e(TAG, "External storage is not writable"); //This line does not show anything on the log. So, esExternalStorageWritable returns false.
File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);//Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (!rootDir.canWrite())
{
  Log.d(TAG, "cannot write in the root: "+rootDir.toString()+", space: "+rootDir.getUsableSpace()+", can read: "+rootDir.canRead()+", list: "+rootDir.list());
}
```

Function isExternalStorageWritable() is implemented as follows:

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable()
{
  String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This always goes inside the if statement where I'm checking if rootDir can write. The rootDir.canRead also returns false. The free space on the device is returned as 2.2GB.

The mkdirs in later lines after that fails because it cannot write to root. Any ideas, suggestions? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had to manually give permission in settings on the watch for it to work. Basically go to: Settings -> Permissions -> Your app, and check if storage is disabled (it was in my case). Click once to toggle the value.

Remember to have write permission on manifest.